# ZF2 autoloading strategy for development and production with git/composer

Tags: git, zend-framework2, composer-php, autoload

I'm using Zend Framework 2 and started with the ZendSkeletonApplication. Locally I work with composer and it uses the `vendor/autoload.php` for autoloading. The problem is that `vendor/autoload.php` and `vendor/composer` is not included in git. (gitignore)

So my questions are:

- Do I have to edit the [init_autoloader.php](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/init_autoloader.php) that is shipped with the ZendSkeletonApplication?
- What is the best practice to handle composer, git and autoloading in development and production?
- Should I use a large classmap for autoloading in production?
- Composer is never used in production environment?

By the way I work with a Zend Server where the ZF2 library is preinstalled and I have a private package under `vendor` folder which is not on packagist.

Comment: You need to commit your composer.json and composer.lock files to your production server, and run a composer install on your production server.

Comment: @STLMikey Like I discussed with ROLO the problem is that I work with a Zend Server where the ZF2 library is preinstalled and I have a private package under `vendor` which is not on packagist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composer should be managing all the app dependencies within `vendor/`. Even if you already have a copy of ZF2 on the server, you should let composer do it's thing and install an app-specific copy. As well as keeping all the dependencies in one place this means you can easily have apps on the same server using different versions of ZF2, and easily upgrade/downgrade as you need to.

Composer can install packages not listed on packagist, either directly from source control or from zip/gzip files and so on. So let it take care of your private package as well.

You should be able to completely delete your `vendor/` folder and then restore it again just by running `composer install`. If you're not already in that position then I'd suggest you try and get there - it will make your life easier.

Answering your specific questions:

> Do I have to edit the init_autoloader.php that is shipped with the ZendSkeletonApplication?

No.

> What is the best practice to handle composer, git and autoloading in development and production?

The skeleton app uses the best practices:

- `vendor/` should be excluded from source control
- `composer.json` and `composer.lock` should both be in source control

> Should I use a large classmap for autoloading in production?

Classmaps always provide a performance boost over the standard autoloader. How much of a difference this makes depends on your app.

> Composer is never used in production environment?

The composer autoloader is, yes. Personally I have `composer install` as part of my automated deployment process to populate the `vendor/` folder when I deploy a new version.

Comment: Thanks, that all make sense. But composer should really pull my private package from git? Then I have to split my development into 2 git repositories. One for the main application and one for my private package?

Comment: Normally libraries of your own creation that you have in vendor are there because you want to be able to use them in other applications as well. So it makes sense for it to have its own git repo.

Comment: You are wrong with the classmap part in general. While it might be beneficial to have a small classmap loaded on every request, there is the downside of having to load the whole classmap on every request. If the classmap file gets big enough, this will be slower than the normal autoloading process! So a classmap is NOT ALWAYS faster. In fact, if you generate an optimized autoloader with Composer, it is a good idea to actually measure if this really optimizes things.

Comment: Fair enough, always worth measuring. I've never seen a performance degradation using a classmap though, even one with 10s of thousands of entries. Since the classmap should be cached by your opcache, this should negate most of the performance hit of loading in such a file.

Answer (score 0):

they are in gitignore because you have to download composer on the server side and push composer.json to install required packages

Comment: hmm..we are using Zend Server, so we don't need the ZF2 library. But if we'd use composer on the server it would download/install ZF2 twice.

Comment: you have to write in composer.json what you want, that's why there are two distinct sections require & [require-dev](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#require-dev)

Comment: I don't get it. If I install an external module that requires "zendframework/zendframework" than the whole framework get installed under "vendor/", or not?

Comment: sorry, now i see your point and i don't know how to help, never faced something like this

Comment: I think it's not a bad idea. If I put the `zendframework/zendframework` under require-dev in the main composer.json file then it could work. Also I set a gitignore for all vendor modules. The next problem is that I have a private module which is not on packagist. Perhaps I have to move it to `module` folder or try to make a private package. ([https://github.com/composer/satis](https://github.com/composer/satis))